# Need clarification on timers in JMeter

Tags: performance, for-loop, integration-testing, jmeter

I studied that there are timers available in JMeter. In this constant delay timer, who sets constant time. Whether jmeter puts the delay time between the thread requests or user has to set the time. If the user sets, Where can he set the timer in tool. If anybody knows can you please share your answers.

Answer (score 3):

> By default, a JMeter thread sends requests without pausing between each request.

If you add a Timer element, then

> The timer will cause JMeter to delay a certain amount of time  before  each sampler which is in its  scope.

Adding a Constant Timer element in a thread group will produce the delay configured in `Thread Delay` property before each request in the thread group.

Answer (score 0):

You set the value on the Timer Module.  You can parametrize this to a variable if you'd like.

Check out the [user manual](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers) - it will answer all your timer questions. If, after reading - you still have questions, feel free to re-ask.